# пользовательская коллекция C#

Tags: c#

Есть пользовательский класс наследующий от **List**

```
class EpochCollection:List<Epoch>
```

как мне правильно реализовать метод `GetRange (int, int)`
в `EpochCollection` чтобы он создавал новый экземпляр `EpochCollection`, с обрезанной в соответствии с заданными границами частью соответствующей  списку, а часть класса, определяемую мной в  `EpochCollection` брал из исходного объекта без изменения?

Или вместо наследования от `List` предпочтительнее описывать собственную коллекцию подобно тому как это описано [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.ienumerator(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: вообще рекомендуют не наследоваться от коллекций, а включать их как поля

Comment: Насколько приемлема следующая реализация:

   
public EpochCollection GetRange(int index, int count)
        {
             Res = (EpochCollection)this.Clone();
            Res.Clear();
            for (int i = index; i < count; i++)
                Res.Add(this[i]);

            return Res;
        }

Comment: а в чем смысле клонирования и последующего очищения если потом опять заполнять? ну и весь необходимый код стоит добавить в вопрос

Answer (score 1):

```
public class EpochCollection : IEnumerable<Epoch>
{
    private List<Epoch> _source;

    private EpochCollection(List<Epoch> source)
    {
        _source = source;
    }

    public EpochCollection GetRange(int index, int count)
    {
        return new EpochCollection(_source.GetRange(index, count));
    }

    public IEnumerator<Epoch> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _source.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _source.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Добавьте необходимые паблик конструкторы и методы.